# Elasticsearch fields only for _source

Tags: elasticsearch

It is a good solution for convenience, if I put some data into elasticsearch index, which fields only using in _source parameter, not for search, or sort? Theese datas are stored in SQL too, but it's easier to access from elasticsearch, not needed plus SQL call. Is this a good direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can access the field value from `_source` if you want to avoid the call to SQL, and better performance. And yes, IMO it's a good direction if you are thinking to call SQL just for retrieving these field values. fetching values from ES will be more efficient.

You can and should disable the [index option](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index.html) on the field, where you don't need to search.

Also, refer to [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-source-filtering.html) for more information.